# Что даст в плане защиты от реверсинга подпись сборки цифровым сертификатом?

Tags: c#, .net, защита

**Цель:** обеспечение должного уровня защиты от реверсинга сборки.

**Что уже было уже испробовано:** была сделана подпись строгим именем всех сборок проекта, но по факту она ничего не дает и тупо снимается рефлексилом. Была мысль сделать отправку на сервер каких либо параметров, например `SHA1Token` (`sha1` хеш из последних 8 байт публичного ключа). Т.е. расчет был на то, что реверсер не сможет подделать токен, но к сожалению идея не удалась, публичный ключ (а из него и токен) можно выделить той же утилитой `sn.exe` из комплекта студии.

**Вопрос:** что может дать для защиты использование (тестовых\коммерческих) цифровых сертификатов (подпись при помощи `signtool`), какие отличия от подписи строгим именем? Можно ли накладывать одно на другое (сертификат на строгую подпись)?

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но мне казалось что все подписи - только защита от подделок, если что-то расковыряет ваше приложение он подпись обратно не поставит и пользователь будет видить что это самопал... Защиты от реверса подпись не даёт, это задача обфускаторов и прочего...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Задачи цифровой подписи - удостоверение авторства и неизменности. То есть, для подписанного блока данных можно сказать кто его подписал и что с момента подписания блок данных не изменился. К защите от реверсинга подпись отношения не имеет.